# Video learning for database design

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I'm trying to learn good relational database design (using mysql and php if that makes any difference). I've already done some database work, so I'm not totally clueless, but I suspect that my solutions may not have adhered to best practices for efficient searching, optimization, etc.

Can someone suggest a good set of videos on the topic? If you know something is superb or has really made a difference in your own learning, please post your suggestion. Prefer videos, but books (as long as they're not too huge) are ok too. But prefer videos.

Thank you

Comment: I have nothing in the way of videos, but I suspect I might have some advice if you shared some code and explained the parts you are unsure of.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would be sooo happy if I could recommend some fine videos, but I can't think any of them. Especially in database design, which is quite a complicated topic, I will not recommend videos. The fastest way isn't the shortest all the time.

If you would like to get some theoretical introduction to the topic, I could recommend the classic Ullman-Widom - A First Course in Database Systems book. It's quite huge, but it contains information that you won't use. Anyway, it sums up the theory of database design on the first 130 pages and it's really nice to read. It wil help to get your SQL to a higher level, too. You can find some information about using databases with PHP, XML and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [www.vtc.com](http://www.vtc.com) - they have training videos on just about everything, including database design, modelling and optimisation for most platforms.  Some of them are free to view online as well.